# Detectar si un argumento en Python (argv) contiene dobles comillas (")

Tags: python

Necesito un módulo de Python que me ayude a detectar **si un argumento argv tiene dobles comillas (") dentro**.

Por ejemplo: Tengo un módulo que detecta si la sintaxis de una IP es correcta y devuelve "Correcto" o "Incorrecto". Necesito ver si la IP pasada por el usuario contiene " para decir que no es correcto.

Ejemplos de IP que deberían ser correctas:

192.168."2".4

192.168."2.4

Creo que la razón por la que no puedo hacer esto es que los argumentos de Python asumen las comillas dobles como caracteres comunes y los ignora directamente.

Necesito que este módulo sea independiente del OS que se esté usando y que sea lo más simple posible para que lo puedan usar usuarios novatos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que recibes en `argv` es una lista de cadenas. Las cadenas tienen métodos para saber si contienen o no un carácter concreto. Por ejemplo puedes usar `caracter in cadena` para averiguarlo.

Así, podrías hacer algo como:

```
import sys

parametro = sys.argv[1]
if "'" in parametro:
   print("El parámetro contiene una comilla simple (apóstrofe)")
   quit()
if '"' in parametro:
   print("El parámetro contiene comillas dobles")
   quit()
print("OK. El parámetro no tiene comillas.")
```

**Otra cosa diferente** es que quizás esas comillas no lleguen siquiera a aparecer dentro de `sys.argv` a pesar de que el usuario las haya tecleado en la línea de comandos, y esto es porque el propio operativo (el *shell*) las elimina, y Python aqui no tiene nada que ver ni puede hacer nada al respecto.

Por ejemplo, el intérprete de comandos de Windows elimina las comillas dobles (`"`) pero no las simples (`'`), por lo que funcionará así:

```
C:\> python ejemplo.py 192.168."2".4
OK. El parámetro no tiene comillas.

C:\> python ejemplo.py 192.168.'2'.4
El parámetro contiene una comilla simple (apóstrofe)
```

En cambio un *shell* unix como `bash`, procesa tanto comillas dobles como simples (aunque tienen distinto significado para él) y las elimina de la entrada tras haberlas procesado, por lo que se comportaría así:

```
~$ python ejemplo.py 192.168."2".4
OK. El parámetro no tiene comillas.

~$ python ejemplo.py 192.168.'2'.4
OK. El parámetro no tiene comillas.
```

La razón de este comportamiento es que las comillas son especiales para el *shell*, que las trata como una forma de agrupar varias palabras en un solo argumento, pero no se las pasa al programa que esté siendo ejecutado. Python ya no recibe comilla ninguna, sino que en ambos casos recibe la cadena `192.168.2.4`.

Puesto que son especiales para el shell, si quieres que no lo sean (y por tanto se le pasen al programa en ejecución como parte del argumento) tienes que *escaparlas*, que consiste en ponerles un `\` delante (aunque de nuevo la forma de escapar puede depender del *shell* en particular, pero ésta funciona para Windows y para bash):

**Windows**:

```
C:\> python ejemplo.py 192.168.\"2\".4
El parámetro contiene comillas dobles
```

**bash**

```
~$ python ejemplo.py 192.168.\"2\".4
El parámetro contiene comillas dobles

~$ python ejemplo.py 192.168.\'2\'.4
El parámetro contiene una comilla simple (apóstrofe)
```

## Ampliación

Ya que las comillas son especiales para el shell, algunos shells pueden incluso dar errores sintácticos si no las usas adecuadamente. Por ejemplo, si las abres pero no las cierras, pueden quedar esperando a la comilla de cierre:

Es el caso de `bash`. Mira:

```
~$ python ejemplo.py 192.168."2.4
>
```

El prompt `>` que aparece se debe a que se abrieron unas comillas antes del 2, pero no se han cerrado. Bash está esperando a que escribas más cosas hasta que las cierres. Si en ese punto pones `"` y pulsas Intro, bash dará por bueno el comando e invocará a Python, pasándole en `sys.argv[1]` una cadena que tiene un retorno de carro tras el 4 (pero en la que de todas formas no habrá comillas porque el shell las eliminó).

Windows parece ser más permisivo con esto. Si abres una comilla y no la cierras, en vez de suponer que el argumento ocupa varias líneas (windows no lo soporta), simplemente cierra por tí las comillas que faltaban (poniendo otras al final de la línea). Y las elimina igualmente del argumento, con lo que Python no las ve de todas formas:

```
C:\> python ejemplo.py 192.168."2.4
OK. El parámetro no tiene comillas.
```

Comment: Entonces cuento con que no tiene fácil solución, no me merece la pena hacer nada al respecto ya que no hay una orden de Python con la que solucionarlo sin tener que escapar los caracteres ". Muchas gracias por la respuesta!